# Jquery append and height property

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a strange problem when I append content to a div with JQuery, the height of this div is not updated. 
I made a JSFiddle for you to see the problem (I tried to make it as simple as possible)

http://jsfiddle.net/hf66v/5/

---

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    SomeContent
</div>
```

which become :

```
<div id="container">
    SomeContent
    <div class="dateDiv date1">
        <span class="dateTitle">Date2</span><br>09/10
    </div>
    <div class="dateDiv date2">
        <span class="dateTitle">Date2</span><br>10/12
    </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS :

```
div.dateDiv  {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

div.date1 {
    float: left;
}

div.date2 {
    float: right;
}
```

Content is added this way :

```
$("#container").append("<div class='dateDiv date1'><span class='dateTitle'>Date1</span><br>09/10</div>");
$("#container").append("<div class='dateDiv date2'><span class='dateTitle'>Date2</span><br>10/12</div>");
```

I did not found any answer about this. Is that because I set a "float" CSS property ? (I'm not used to it)

Any ideas ?

Comment: It is exactly because you are using the float CSS property. You can add a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` (or more complicated stuff to deal with floating elements) after the 2 dates to "force" resize of the container.

Comment: That is happening due to the `float: left` and `float: right` rules in your css.

Comment: Yes, floats do not add to the height of the container.  If you have an element which must come after the floats (as the `clear: both;` requires) then these elements take height and have to come after the float so the float then contributes to the container height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. Append a 'clearer' div after you append the two divs.

Modify your jQuery like this.

```
$("#container").append("<div class='dateDiv date1'><span class='dateTitle'>Date1</span><br>09/10</div>");
$("#container").append("<div class='dateDiv date2'><span class='dateTitle'>Date2</span><br>10/12</div>");
$("#container").append("<div class='clearer'></div>");
```

And add this to your CSS

```
.clearer{
    clear: both;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hf66v/7/)

Or if your html structure is not going to change, you **ONLY** need to add this to your css:

```
hr{    
    clear: both;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hf66v/8/)

Comment: Best response. My problem was exactly about the hr line being between the two date divs. So I only need to add `hr{clear: both;}`. Thank you !
}

Comment: works best in combination with @hsz response (add `overflow:hidden` to container) to have the top margin property working on the hr element.

Answer (score 1):

You can set to the `#container` following style:

```
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hf66v/6/

Comment: That solved the problem ! Do you or anyone has an explanation to this ? (I first though it will cut off the bottom of my date divs)

Comment: I believe it is because my container has no fixed height

Comment: @Apolo Yes. if you set container's height to `10px` it fill cut its content.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I gave you +1 but someone seems to dislike your answer, and no comment...